# Como recorrer una lista y mostrar los datos por consola en QT creator c++

Tags: c++, lista, qt

Buenas,
Estoy creando el siguiente método:

```
void MainWindow::agregarProyecto(QString nombre, QString descripcion, QString directorio)
{
    proyecto *unProyecto = new proyecto (nombre,descripcion,directorio);
    qDebug("Se va agregar el proyecto a la lista");
    listaProyectos.append(*unProyecto);
    QList<proyecto>::iterator i;
    for(i = listaProyectos.begin(); i!=listaProyectos.end(); i++){
        qDebug << (*i).getNombre();
    }
    delete unProyecto;
}
```

¿Como puedo recorrer la lista utilizando un iterador y mostrar los datos por consola?

Comment: Imagino que `listaProyectos` es algo tal que `QList<proyecto> listaProyectos`, ¿no? El problema es que tengo que imaginarlo... porque puede que no sea así. También tengo que asumir que eres consciente que con `listaProyectos.append(*unProyecto);` estás haciendo una copia del objeto apuntado por `unProyecto` y no una copia del puntero... pero no puedo estar seguro de si lo sabes o no porque no has indicado qué error te estás encontrando...

Comment: ... Tampoco puedo saber si a raiz de lo anterior has implementado correctamente el constructor copia de `Proyecto` para que `getNombre` te devuelva un nombre en vez de una cadena en blanco. Deberías editar la pregunta y añadir la información que te falta.

Comment: Claro intente simplificar la pregunta para que no sea muy extensa. Puede que existan cosas que no se entienda. A modo de aclaración. listaProyecto es una lista de tipo proyecto, es decir "QList<proyecto> listaProyectos". La misma esta definida en "mainWindows.h"

Comment: ¿Con _"claro"_ te refieres a que todo lo comentado lo has tenido en cuenta y está hecho y aun así falla? Que intentes simplificar la pregunta está genial siempre y cuando ofrezcas la información mínima que permita entender el problema. La pregunta, tal y como está, no aclara qué es lo que no te funciona... si es que no salen datos, si salen mal, si sale algún error...

Comment: Entiendo, mi problema esta al momento de hacer el qDebug. Ya que no se si realmente esta bien la forma de crear un iterador para recorrer la lista de proyectos.

Comment: El mayor problema que le veo a ese iterador es una tontería y es que haces un post-incremento en vez de un pre-incremento. En cuanto al uso de qDebug... los proyectos permiten deshabilitar o modificar el comportamiento de `qDebug`, si quieres asegurarte de sacar el mensaje por la consola considera usar `cout` (por ejemplo)

Comment: Ok, cuando te referís a un pre-incremento, te referís al valor del indice (i), osea debería decrementar (i--). De todos modos agradezco tu sugerencia.

Comment: `i++` es postincremento  y `++i` es preincremento. El postincremento puede conllevar crear una copia del iterador en cada iteración y eso merma el rendimiento... el rendimiento perdido puede ser imperceptible o no, depende del algoritmo y del compilador

Comment: podrias usar el nuevo standar c++11 y hacer algo similar a `for(auto elemento: {tu lista}){qDebug()<< elemento}`

Answer (score 1):

Para recorrer una lista (un QList) lo mas cómodo es el iterador automático del comando for, activa si no lo tienes la especificación del compilador a C11, añadiendo en tu .pro.

```
 CONFIG  += c++11
```

Suponiendo que "Proyecto" es una estructura o un objeto y que "Lista" es un `QList< Proyecto >`

```
for (Proyecto ElProyecto : Lista )
   qDebug() << ElProyecto.Dato1 << ElProyecto.Dato2;
```